# Need to fetch background location even when the app is killed

Tags: android-workmanager

Im using workmanger to fetch background location and stored in local storage using Realm.I schedule the work interval of 15 minutes its works first time correctly but when I killed the app it does work.How do I acheive this background location fetching job and is there any way to do this job?

This is my Work constrain

```
 private fun initializeWorker() {
        val constraints = Constraints.Builder()
            .setRequiresDeviceIdle(false)
            .build()

        // Create the work request
        val periodicWorkRequest =
            PeriodicWorkRequestBuilder<LocationWorker>(15, TimeUnit.MINUTES,5,TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                .setConstraints(constraints)
                .addTag(userId)
                .build()

        // Enqueue the work request

        WorkManager.getInstance(this).enqueueUniquePeriodicWork(
            userId,
            ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.KEEP, periodicWorkRequest
        )
        val workInfoLiveData: LiveData<List<WorkInfo>> =
            WorkManager.getInstance(this)
                .getWorkInfosForUniqueWorkLiveData(Constants.LOCATION_WORK_MANGER)

        workInfoLiveData.observe(this) { workInfoList ->
            if (workInfoList.isNotEmpty()) {
                val workInfo = workInfoList[0]
                when (workInfo.state) {
                    WorkInfo.State.SUCCEEDED -> {
                        println("WorkInfo State SUCCEEDED")
                        // getLocationDataFromRealm(userId)
                    }
                    WorkInfo.State.BLOCKED -> {
                        println("WorkInfo State BLOCKED")
                    }
                    WorkInfo.State.ENQUEUED -> {
                        println("WorkInfo State ENQUEUED")
                    }
                    WorkInfo.State.FAILED -> {
                        println("WorkInfo State FAILED")
                    }
                    WorkInfo.State.RUNNING -> {
                        println("WorkInfo State RUNNING")
                    }
                    WorkInfo.State.CANCELLED -> {
                        println("WorkInfo State CANCELLED")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.location.Geocoder
import android.location.Location
import android.util.Log
import androidx.lifecycle.Lifecycle
import androidx.lifecycle.ProcessLifecycleOwner
import androidx.localbroadcastmanager.content.LocalBroadcastManager
import androidx.work.Worker
import androidx.work.WorkerParameters
import com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices
import com.google.android.gms.location.Priority
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.CancellationTokenSource
import com.mytask.realm.Database
import com.mytask.realm.LocationModel
import com.mytask.realm.UserModel
import com.mytask.utils.Constants
import com.mytask.utils.PreferenceManager
import io.realm.kotlin.ext.query
import kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers
import kotlinx.coroutines.runBlocking
import kotlinx.coroutines.withContext
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
import java.util.*


class LocationWorker(context: Context, workerParams: WorkerParameters) :
    Worker(context, workerParams) {

    private val fusedLocationClient: FusedLocationProviderClient =
        LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(context)
    private val geocoder = Geocoder(context)
    private val _context = context
    private val preferenceManager = PreferenceManager(context)
    override fun doWork(): Result = runBlocking {
        try {
           getLocation(context = _context)
            Result.success()
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.e("", "Error getting location", e)
            Result.failure()
        }
    }

    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    private suspend fun getLocation(context: Context) {
        val time: String =
            SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault()).format(Date())
        withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            fusedLocationClient.getCurrentLocation(
                Priority.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY,
                CancellationTokenSource().token
            )
                .addOnSuccessListener { location ->
                      if (location != null ) {
                        Database.usersRealmOpen.writeBlocking {
                            val currentLocation = LocationModel().apply {
                                latitude = location.latitude
                                longitude = location.longitude
                                timeStamp = time
                                address = updateAddressText(location)
                            }
                            val userId =   preferenceManager.getString(Constants.KEY_USER_ID).toString()
                            val user: UserModel? = query<UserModel>("userId == $0", userId).first().find()
                            if (user == null) {
                                println("New user")
                                val userModel = UserModel().apply {
                                    this.userId = userId
                                    locations.add(currentLocation)
                                }
                                copyToRealm(userModel)
                            } else {
                                println("Old user")
                                findLatest(user)?.locations?.add(currentLocation)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }.addOnFailureListener {
                        Result.retry()
                }
        }

    }

    private fun updateAddressText(currentLocation: Location): String {

        val latitude = currentLocation.latitude
        val longitude = currentLocation.longitude
        val addressText = StringBuilder()
        return geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1)?.let { addresses ->
            val address = addresses[0]
            addressText.append(address.locality).append(", ")
            addressText.append(address.adminArea).append(", ")
            addressText.append(address.countryName).append(", ")
            addressText.toString()
        } ?: ""
    }
    companion object {
        private const val TAG = "LocationWorker"
    
    }
}
```